# Saving array with JQuery in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to save two values entered by the client in JQuery using Rails. I am newbie to JQuery and I can't find a way to do it.

My **index.html.erb** is as follows:

```
<div >
    <p class="mod1_title">Plot</p>
    <div class="mod1_boxed">
      <strong>Data1:</strong>
      <%= form_tag do %>
          <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module1", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 3500", id: "user_entry" %></br>
      <strong>Data2:</strong></br>
      <%= text_field_tag "user_entry_module2", nil, placeholder: "Bsp. 5", id: "user_entry_2" %></br>
          <%= submit_tag "submit" %>
      <%end%>
    </div>  
</div>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 600px"></div>

<script >

    $(function () {
         // Display the month, day, and year. 
          var dt = new Date();
          var month = dt.getMonth()+1;
          var day = dt.getDate();
          var year = dt.getFullYear();

        var seriesOptions = [];
        //Calling each action
        var calls = ['get_data_con','get_data_pro'];
        var names = ['fig1','fig2'];

        $("#user_entry, #user_entry_2").change(function(){
          var number_value = [$(this).val()];
          alert(number_value);

        });//alert

   });

</script>
```

In the code below, I am trying to save `data1` and `data2`:

```
 $("#user_entry, #user_entry_2").change(function(){
              var number_value = [$(this).val()];
              alert(number_value);

  });//alert
```

It saves the variables BUT it shows the alert just after each data is introduced. I just want both `data1` and `data2` to be saved and only *then* the alert shows the array `[data1, data2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Your event is `$('SOMETHING').change(function{})`. The **change event** is called every times someone (or some script) change the value of the input. Moreover, you datas looks like being submitted by your form (`<%= form_tag do %>`) and not with Jquery.

**There is a way to do it:**

You should use `$.post()` (documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) if you want to save your datas with Javascript and not with the html (generated by rails) form. When it's done, you can handle the response and alert your values. Something like this should work:

```
$.post( "/path/to/controller/create", function( data ) {
  alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
});
```

Comment: But with $.post() I am requesting data from the server. I want to save just data1 and data2 and then send these two entries from my javascript to the controllers(do so calculations) and finally (result from controller back to view)  do some plots in the javascript code. I don't get the idea of $.post().

Comment: POST is for **sending** data to your controller.

- **First** : You send your data with the `$.post()` ajax request.
- **Second** : Your controller receive those data and save them (+ calculation if you want).
- **Third** : Your controller respond with the calculated value, and those values are gonna be catch by the `success` callback of your `$.post()` function